# elasticsearch message field value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am sending `json` messages to `logstash` getting indexed by `elasticsearch` and managed to setup the UI dashboard in `Kibana`. I would like to filter the data by the message fields and cannot figure out how or where to do this. An example of my message:

```
{"message":"{"pubDate":"2014-02-25T13:09:14",
 "scrapeDate":"2014-02-5T13:09:26",
 "Id":"78967",
 "query":"samsung S5",
 "lang":"en"}
```

Right now it counts all these messages coming in but I need to get each message filtered by the fields itself for example like `Id` or `lang` or `query`.
Does this have to be done in the config file or can it be created in `Kibana` interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I assume your json messages is

```
{
   "pubDate":"2014-02-25T13:09:14",
   "scrapeDate":"2014-02-5T13:09:26",
   "Id":"78967",
   "query":"samsung S5",
   "lang":"en"
}
```

When you send your message to logstash, you need to **specify the codec to json**. As show in the configuration below:

```
input {
    stdin {
            codec => json
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
            cluster => "abc"
    }
}
```

Logstash will parsing your message to different field, like the output:

```
{
   "pubDate" => "2014-02-25T13:09:14",
"scrapeDate" => "2014-02-5T13:09:26",
        "Id" => "78967",
     "query" => "samsung S5",
      "lang" => "en",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-02-26T01:36:15.336Z",
      "host" => "AAAAAAAAAA"
 }
```

When you show this data in Kibana, You can use fieldname:value to query and filter what you need. For example, you can query all message with `lang:en`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Appreciate it. I changed the config file as you suggested but not seeing any data come through. I will figure it out but one more question if you don't mind. Where are the log messages stored so that I can clean up that directory when it gets too full.

Comment: also would the conf file not have tcp instead of stdin right?

Comment: would still appreciate any response about the log cleanup

Comment: After Logstash parses the log, the log data will send to elasticsearch and store in it!  you can visit $elasticsearch/data. You can delete all the data there or use elasticsearch API to delete it. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html